# What is the fastest way to get a DataTable into SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, bulkinsert

I have a DataTable in memory that I need to dump straight into a SQL Server temp table.

After the data has been inserted, I transform it a little bit, and then insert a subset of those records into a permanent table.

The most time consuming part of this operation is getting the data into the temp table.

Now, I have to use temp tables, because more than one copy of this app is running at once, and I need a layer of isolation until the actual insert into the permanent table happens.

**What is the fastest way to do a bulk insert from a C# DataTable into a SQL Temp Table?**

I can't use any 3rd party tools for this, since I am transforming the data in memory.

My current method is to create a parameterized SqlCommand:

```
INSERT INTO #table (col1, col2, ... col200) VALUES (@col1, @col2, ... @col200)
```

and then for each row, clear and set the parameters and execute.

There has to be a more efficient way.  I'm able to read and write the records on disk in a matter of seconds...

Comment: How many rows there are in the dataset? How long does it take to insert?

Comment: 200000 rows, upwards of 45 minutes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the [`SqlBulkCopy` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).

Comment: Awesome, but do you know if it can be used on temp tables?

Comment: @John Gietzen - the way I usually do it, is to load into a "real" table - then drop it once you're done.

Comment: Well, that's somewhat doable, but again there are about 10 copies of this app that could be running concurrently.  Do you know if a Bulk Copy can be part of a transaction?

Comment: @John Gietzen - if they're all meant to be separate from each other, load into a "temporary" real table - just generate a unique table name at run time to stop them contending. You can do bulk copy as part of a transaction (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wftd1yfz(v=VS.100).aspx) but I've personally never done that

Comment: GOOD NEWS!  You can use an external transaction, and you can use temp tables!  Down from 20 minutes to 8 seconds!

Answer (score 10):

[SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) will get the data in very fast.

I [blogged not that long ago](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sqlbulkcopy-bulk-load-to-sql-server.html) how to maximise performance. Some stats and examples in there. I compared 2 techniques, 1 using an SqlDataAdapter and 1 using SqlBulkCopy - bottom line was for bulk inserting 100K records, the data adapter approach took ~25 seconds compared to only ~0.8s for SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: +1, but I'm giving the accept to SLaks because he was a hair quicker.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: He's fast and accurate, like a sniper rifle bullet.